# What does "Slurm error: QOSMinNode " mean in Slurm?

Tags: slurm

I got the following error log,

> sbatch: error: QOSMinNode
> sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Job violates accounting/QOS policy (job submit limit, user's size and/or time limits)

what does it mean? I cannot find any "QOSMinNode " error in the Slurm manual.

Answer (score 0):

The `QOSMinNode` is probably the name of a QOS defined on the cluster. You can verify with

```
sacctmgr list qos
```